# How can I include loose files cross-platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

My application has a collection of *.json* files some being user created, and others to be included with the application by default with the potential to be changed (removed, contents updated). I am also trying to find a way to store them so the user can easily access their location *(ie **"...\AppData\Local\Program\Files"** or **"...\Program\Files"**)*, atleast on Desktop.

I've read the about using the **app sandbox** that xamarin provides for cross-platform access to a local storage; though to me it doesn't seem like a fit for what I'm trying to do, as from my understanding it's a location to store files created at runtime.

I also looked into using Visual Studio's **Build Action** property, which feels closer to working in the way I need; but I'm not sure which setting is the best; I tried using **'Content'** but I couldn't seem to find a reliable way to access the files across all platforms, even when using conditional compilation.

A point in any direction is helpful, I was hoping Xamarin might have something built in for this, but if I have to use an outside system I will.

Comment: you can include them in each platform project as Content, or include them in the shared project as Resources (but then you will have to access them as streams, not files).  In either case they will be read-only.

Comment: @Jason If I were to manage them this way, would that still allow for my application to load user generated files (of the same type/json format) that are placed in the same location?

Comment: No, you can’t place user generated files in the app bundle because it is read only.  You can copy files from the app bundle to user writable folders at app startup